# smaller array based on array contents

Tags: php, arrays

I am looking for a way to create a new array based on array contents.

so i've got:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 
        [type] => first_value_i_need 
        [some_id] => 2 
        [hits] => 88 
        [some_other_id] => second_value_i_need 
      )
```

and i would like to get

```
Array ( [0] => 1 
        [app_name] => "first_value_i_need-second_value_i_need" 
        [hits] => "88" 
      )
```

I know that i need some sort of foreach function, but i'm right now lost.

Comment: if that's simple you don't need any foreach

Comment: How about
**Array[app_name] = Array[type].Array[some_other_id]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need any loops as long as you know which keys you need.

```
$old = array(
    0 => 1, 
    'type' => 'first_value_i_need',
    'some_id' => 2, 
    'hits' => 88, 
    'some_other_id' => 'second_value_i_need'
);

$new = array(
    0 => $old[0],
    'app_name' => $old['type'].'-'.$old['some_other_id'],
    'hits' => $old['hits'],
);
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically do you wnat to get rid of the `app_table_id` key ?

You can do `unset($array['app_table_id']);`

And if you need to change some value you can do :

```
$array['app_name'] = $array['some_other_id'];
```

//> Note i posted this before your edit.

Comment: thanks man this will also come in handy later today, thanks in advance, you saved me another slightly dumb question ..! + 10 internets to you..!!